# python: kernel seems to crash, it will restart automatically

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Helllo guys,
Im running jupyter on serveur. I configure the serveur and did **jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root**
I did this when creating my container to use only 7GO:

```
sudo docker run -it --memory="7g" jupyter
```

I created a notebook, containing only these rows

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
from src.connection import create_postgres_engine
postgres_connection = create_postgres_engine('prod')
query1 = """
select
      id,  col1, date, col2, col3
 from s inner join c on s.id = c.id_1
and s.date BETWEEN c.date_beg AND date_end where date >='2020-01-04' and due_date <'2020-04-08';
"""
query1 = pd.read_sql_query(query1, postgres_connection[0], coerce_float=False)
```

After 3, 4 minutes i got this error
kernel seems to crash, it will restart automatically.

Please who can help me?
I spend 2 days on it, and didn't got what happens.

Comment: How many row is the query expected to return? Could they fill up your RAM?

Comment: 13 millions rows.

Comment: Try with less data!

Comment: it works for one or two days for example. But i want to understand the cause :/

Comment: @KlausD. do you know why it should happens please? ??????

Comment: It's simply too much data for your RAM.

Comment: thank you for your response! but with limited ram, the prob should take too much time and not crash diractly ! what do you think?

Comment: If you limit the memory of the container, the OS kernel is just going to kill it once the limit is reached.